# How to Access Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript . I just want to know how can I access an array which when I display through alert it shows==> (123,456),(987,1245) .
Now If I want to get the value 123 what should I execute ? I tried  with array1[0][0] but it failed. Please help

In google Map api v3 I am fetching paths through this ==>

```
paths=polygon.getPath().getArray();
```

And when I print it through alert it is showing 
(51.494 , -93.323),(12.2323,34.43221) . now how can I access 51.494 ?

Comment: pls post your code so that I will have a better idea..

Comment: Are you using Jquery in your project?

Comment: Why does it fail, whats the error? What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create an array as follow:

```
var concertArray = [
    {name: "Billy Joel", value: 99, image: "equal.png"},
    {name: "Bryan Adams", value: 89, image: "higher.png"},
    {name: "Brian Adams", value: 25, image: "lower.png"}
];

    var concertName = concertArray[0].name;
    var concertPrice = parseFloat(concertArray[0].value);
    var concertImage = concertArray[0].image;
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

This should help get you started.

```
var arr = [ [123, 456], [987, 1245] ];

console.log(arr[0][0]); // 123
```

But please read the [MDN docs for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var arr = '(51.494 , -93.323),(12.2323,34.43221)';
var res = arr.replace(/[()]/g, "").split(",");;
alert(res[0]);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me ! I have use it in that array returned by google map api getArray() .

Comment: What is the error you are getting? did you try like this?
var arr =polygon.getPath().getArray();